# how to print simple hello world using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **HTML** drop down and want to print simple console text on change of drop down item. I use the following code:

```js
$('.pm').on('change', "select[name='pay']:", function() {
  console.log("Hello World");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I want when click on A gives 'A' on the console, click on B gives 'B' on console.. **OR** click on any option gives 
**HELLO WORLD** on the console

Comment: remove `: ` from `"select[name='pay']:"` and it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this).val()` to get the selected value of the option that is selected.

**demo**

```js
$('.pm').on('change', "select[name='pay']", function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log("selected is " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @user_123 I'm sorry what do you mean?

Comment: when click on A it shows 'A' and when click on B it shows both 'A' and 'B'. @Carsten Løvbo Andersen....

Comment: @user_123 so if i click on D you want it to show all the previous also? aka A B C D

Comment: When click on A show 'A' only and next time when click on B show 'B' only...@Carsten Løvbo Andersen.... Here, I attach the screenshot of current scenario..

Comment: @user_123 Updated.

Comment: how this could be the accepted answer??  want when click on A gives 'A' on the console, click on B gives 'B' on console.. OR click on any option gives HELLO WORLD on the console ??

Comment: @SunilGarg it's up to the OP to decide what answer he thinks solved his problem the best. I believe you are just mad because you answer was removed

Comment: @SunilGarg I think **you** misunderstood the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```js
$('select[name="pay"]').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log("Hello World!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('select[name="pay"]').on('change',  function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pm">
  <select name="pay">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use this script
//$(this).val() gives the value of option selected, not the text.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=pay]').change(function() {
        console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());
    });
});
```

Comment: since, there is no value in your options, you have to take out the text of the selected option.

Comment: `$(this).val()` would also return the same as `.text()` in this case

Comment: Just as a side note to OP. In your original code you used delegate event binding but accept an answer using direct binding. Only mentioning it in case you actually needed the delegate event binding you posted as it otherwise will break your code if the select is injected. If not, than it's all good :)

Comment: Another option is to use plain `this.value` as there is no need to create an additional jquery wrapper in this case.